# How $\sqrt{\cos (106.3) + i \sin (106.3)} = \cos 53.15 + i \sin 53.15$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is find sqrt of $-7 +24i$
solution:
$$\sqrt{-7+24i} = z$$
$$-7+24i = z^2$$
$r=25$, $106.3^\circ$

$$\sqrt{\cos (106.3) + i \sin (106.3)} = \cos 53.15 + i \sin 53.15 /*HOW?*/$$

thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: Your expression should have two square roots.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks, shouldn't you use write it in the answer instead of comment?

Comment: @problematic, I think the mink is sufficient, you are free to write one & accept that

Answer (score 2):

Using $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ ([Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)),
$$
\left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta\right)^{1/2} = \left(e^{i \theta}\right)^{1/2} = e^{i \theta / 2} = \cos \left(\theta/2\right) + i \sin \left(\theta/2\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

De Moivre's formula
$$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$$

$$\sqrt{\cos (106.3) + i \sin (106.3)} = \cos {1\over2}(106.3) + i \sin {1\over2}(106.3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$, and solve $z^2=-7+24i$:
$$x^2-y^2=-7\\2xy=24,$$or, multiplying by $x^2$:
$$x^4-x^2y^2=x^4-144=-7x^2.$$
This yields $$x^2=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{625}}{2}=9,-16,$$then, keeping only the positive solution $x^2=9$,
$$z=\pm(3+4i).$$